# Make single line in div selected when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to make a single line in a div highlighted when clicked (not the whole div selected)

I can use jquery or javascript as needed.

The div new lines are separated by br tag.

```
<div class="selectline">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccc<br>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccc<br>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccc<br>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Please note: the text needs to be highlited - as in if I right and click and select copy it will copy the entire line.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pxuJe/1/ ?

Comment: erm, this is not a duplicate. I want to highlight each row sepratealy when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle, I believe it will do what you need, including removing selected by clicking on the selected item, http://jsfiddle.net/LAgqa/

Note the HTML, you'll have to wrap each line in a tag, I selected span in this example.

```
$('.selectline > span').click(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.hasClass('selected')) {
        t.removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        t.parent().children('span').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: edit: actually this isn't 'highlighted' for copy for example...any idea?

Comment: now that you've clarified/redefined 'highlighting' take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse